# What does webpack code splitting mean and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what webpack does is bundle up all your files into one and then serves them to the client to reduce requests. Afterwards, the client still has to load that file for your app to work, so in order to make it faster, code splitting lets the client loads up different parts of your app on demand, correct?

I'm not sure how to do that with the below code from the docs. So if I put the below code in a file that has already been loaded, the first parameter refer to the dependencies and the 2nd refer to the callback. That means anything I want to do with the dependencies have to go in the callback, correct?

```
require.ensure(["module-a", "module-b"], function() {
  var a = require("module-a");
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code splitting** is one of the most compelling features of webpack. It allows you to split your code into various bundles which you can then load on demand 
for example when a user navigates to a matching route, or on an event from the user. This allows for smaller bundles, and allows you to control resource load prioritization

***Split app and vendor code***
var webpack = require("webpack");

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
    vendor: ["jquery", "underscore", ...],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js")
  ]
};
```

This will remove all modules in the vendor chunk from the app chunk. The bundle.js will now contain just your app code, without any of its dependencies. These are in vendor.bundle.js.

In your HTML page load vendor.bundle.js before bundle.js.

```
<script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

[More Info](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx)

[React code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

Comment: so this will just make your page load faster? i mean it will still need the vendor bundle to work right? so doesn't that still need to be loaded? how is this better?